# Joomla specific admin user group to manage non-admin users of same country

Tags: php, joomla

I am using Joomla 3.5.1 and I have no prior experience with Joomla. I know a little of PHP and SQL.

My goal is to allow admins in User Group C to manage users that are of the same country as them.

I have 2 questions.

1) I have used the Joomla User Profile Plugin to add a country field (set as required field). I have gone to plugins/user/profile/profiles/profile.xml and changed the corresponding code to a dropdown code with my predefined country values:

```
<field
        name="country"
        type="list"
        id="country"
        description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_DESC"
        filter="string"
        label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL"
        size="30">
        <option value="Country1">Country1</option>
        <option value="Country2">Country2</option>
        <option value="Country3">Country3</option>
        ...
     </field>
```

Yes, I am aware that this file may be overwritten during update etc. This is fine with me for now.

How do I further modify the code to make the field's default selected value = the country that the admin is in?

2) Under Users > Manage. How do I make it such that if the admin who is logged in, is in User Group C - the list of users shown will only be those that are in the same country as him? I also need him to be unable to edit admins that are the same/higher level than him.

I appreciate any help, or even just a direction to the path of any files I should be looking at, thanks!

Comment: I have written an article on this. You can have a look http://smartyblog.com/adding-custom-fields-to-joomla-registration-using-profile-plugin/.

Comment: Hi @AmitRay, I think I need a little more than what your article offers:)